# node + jest + mocking event handler callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a function in my Node.js code which I am trying to test but I want to mock out `processStreamData`:

```js
async functionToTest(stream) {
  // Run some checks on the stream here
  stream.on('data', async (data) => {
    // Run some checks on the data here
    await this.processStreamData(data);
  }).on('finish', () => {
    // Do some processing here
    resolve();
  });
}

async processStreamData(data) {
  ...
}
```

Here is my test:

```js
test('functionToTest success', async (testCase) => {
  try {
    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(`${DATA_DIR}/genericCsv.csv`);
    jest.spyOn(myClass, "processStreamData").mockImplementation();

    await expect(myClass.functionToTest(readStream)).resolves.toEqual(undefined);
    await expect(myClass.processStreamData).toBeCalledWith(expect.anything());

    testCase();
  } catch(exception) {
    console.log(exception);
    testCase.fail(new Error(`Test failed${exception}`));
  };
});
```

It seems like because `processStreamData` is inside an event handler, the original function (rather than the mock) is called.

I've also tried mocking the function via

```js
myClass.processStreamData = jest.fn.mockImplementation()
```

which didn't work.  The original function was still called.

I've done some googling and am well-aware that jest historically has had limitations around this https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/207 but does this still apply?  If not, can someone hand-hold me through the process of how I should set up my mock so it can be used?

Comment: I suggest you avoid using classes as it is harder to test.

Comment: Is myClass an instance of your class or the class itself? What does your import look like